# Pop-up modal does not move in Safari mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile-safari

I have a webpage http://videa.com.tr/. If I enter the page from iPhone Safari and then click 'Gizlilik ve Güvenlik' a modal opens but I cannot slide it to down or up the background slides but not the text inside modal. Except for mobile Safari, it works fine (on Android), and desktop web (haven't tried iPad)

It is just HTML, JS and CSS (no backend code) page.

Comment: Essential reading: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed to colorbox(http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) than my own. So it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

.rb-content-container
has been assigned inline style which is `800px` , switch to `%` on mobile devices using `media Query`
also the popup is displayed by iframe with `width="800"`; switch to 100% i.e `width="100%"`

I guess this should fix it let me if it worked or not

Comment: it did not make any change.